# FParsec: Parameterizing `parray n p` with elements of a list

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

The problem is this: I know I need to parse `n` occurrences of `p`, but I also have a list `xs` from which I need to pass an element to `p` on each application. Passing one value to `p` is easy enough -- `parray n (p xs)` -- but then I don't know which element in the list I need to access.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I arrived at was:

```
let rec pmap f xs =
    match xs with
    | x :: xs -> parse { let! y = f x
                         let! ys = pmap f xs
                         return y :: ys }
    | [] -> parse { return [] }
```

This can then be used as:

```
let p x = ...
pmap p xs
```

Would still like to hear other ideas!